# Having stack overflow problems in a tree traversal algorithm for an interpreter in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, stack-overflow, interpreter

I am using an interpreter for a simple language in JavaScript. The code looks more or less like this:

```
var interpret = function(term){
    if (!Array.isArray(term)) 
        return term;

    term = [interpret(term[0]), interpret(term[1])];

    if (term[0] && term[0][0] === "add")
        return term[0][1] + term[1];

    if (term[0] && term[0][0] === "mul")
        return term[0][1] * term[1];

    /* ... etc ... */

    return term;
}

console.log(interpret([["mul",[["add",2],2]],3]));
```

The problem is I am having stack overflows by using this algorithm. My question is: what is a fast, recursionless way to transverse a binary-tree in bottom-up order?

Comment: You're going to have to explain your tree schema; that's a really strange-looking form for an expression.

Comment: It is just a binary tree... what is strange about it?

Comment: @Viclib: It doesn't really fit your problem. You're using binary operators, so every node should consist of three parts: the operator name and the two arguments: `["mul", ["add", 2, 2], 3]`. Unless you would use curried functions, which you aren't.

Comment: Yes I am using curried functions...

Comment: @Viclib: In your representation, maybe, but not in your interpreter.

Comment: This is just a minimal example of the algorithm I am using.

Comment: Can you please post an example that leads to a stack overflow? What you posted does log `12` for me without any problems.

Comment: You want me to post the entire code? It is a 150 lines long interpreter for a scheme like language, and the stack overflow is happening in code like `((lambda (((if ((eq 0) (Var 0))) 0) ((add a) ((Recur 0) ((sub (Var 0)) 1))))) 20)`.

Comment: So you're not getting a stack overflow from infinite recursion (as if you had a circular expression), but just from very deep recursion? Then we might be able to help you without the complete code.

Comment: Yes. The code also runs pretty fast, ie, (sum 19) is instantaneous, (sum 20) stacks overflows. The problem is probably the huge amount of recursion, which could be solved if I did the transversal without it. I should also note some parts are like this `if (/*is-apply*/) return interpret(apply(term[0][1],term[1]))` - as in, calling interpret again. The function I posted is most likely enough, though - if it is improved not to use a stack then I'll probably know what to do with my own function.

Comment: I am curious. I would love to see how your language looks.

Comment: @Viclib: Uh, calling `interpret` again might cause problems or at least complicate the solution, since it's no more only strictly recursing a binary tree. Maybe show that part as well.

Comment: Weeeell... actually I don't think there is much that can be done about that, though. After all, you need to further reduce a term after applying a beta-reduction, or else you will not reach normal form, other than calling reduce again a few times. Every recursion is in tail-position, though, so it makes me wonder if even that could be improved. Hmm, but anyway, lets be clear, I just don't have the background on non-recursive transversal so I don't know what techniques could be applied here. Just removing the recursion on that original code will be enough for me to do what I need!

Comment: @Viclib: Check out my answer! It should be able to even cope with that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a strict binary tree, transforming it into [reverse polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) should be easy. You can then operate on that stack without any recursion.

```
var ops = {
    // you might be looking into an autocurry function
    add: function(a) {
        return function(b) {
            return a+b;
        };
    },
    mul: function(a) {
        return function(b) {
            return a*b;
        }
    }
};
function interpret(term) {
    var stack = [term];
    for (var i=0; i<stack.length; )
        if (Array.isArray(stack[i]))
            stack.splice(i, 1, stack[i][1], stack[i][0]);
        else
            i++;
    // now stack is in RPN

    for (var i=0; i<stack.length; i++)
        if (stack[i] in ops)
            stack[i] = ops[stack[i]]; // make operators

    for (var i=1; stack.length>1; )
        if (typeof stack[i] == "function") {
            stack.splice(i-1, 2, stack[i](stack[i-1]));
            i--;
        } else
            i++;

    return stack[0];
}
```

Comment: OK, thanks, I am trying to wrap my head around that. I mean, I understand what you did, but why wouldn't every interpreter for functional languages do the same? Seems like it is much better this way.

Comment: Yeah, kinda :-) However, it is strict evaluation, not lazy. And I just figured out that `lambda`s need a special representation in RPN.

Comment: I don't really buy the idea of lazy evaluation as I think total functional programming makes it irrelevant, as it should be. Hmm...

Comment: I just meant that an interpreter for a functional language often needs to deal with much more than simply evaluating expressions :-)